# c# WPF, No trouble inserting records into primary table, but can't update secondary table record

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, oledbconnection

```
try
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"myconnectionstring_blah_blah";


    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StaffOrders (StaffID, OrderDate, Pants, Boots " + "VALUES (@StaffID, @OrderDate, @Pants, @Boots)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffID", staffid);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", datenow);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pants", pant);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Boots", boot);

    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

     //**********************************************************   
    if(int.Parse(bootsissued) > 0)
    {
        //Update LastBoot in StaffList with today's Date
    }
    //***********************************************************

    connection.Close();

}
catch //blah blah
```

I have two access tables:

```
StaffList:
     ID (autonumber - pk - unique)
     StaffID (indexed unique string)
     LastBoot (Date/Time)
     ...

StaffOrders:
     ID  (autonumber - pk - unique)
     StaffID (indexed unique string) - same as above
     ... (pants, boots, etc)
```

I'm inserting records into `StaffOrders`, but I want to update the record `LastBoot` (from `StaffList`) with the current date, anytime a boot is ordered.

Both tables are in the same access database. I have no problem adding the order records, but I can't seem to `UPDATE` the `LastBoot` record with the current date.

The unique identifier I have to `UPDATE` the appropriate record is `StaffID` not the `ID` autonumber.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DateTime datenow = DateTime.Today; 

        string myconnectionstring = @"//connectionstring";
        OleDbConnection myconnection = new OleDbConnection();
        myconnection.ConnectionString = myconnectionstring;

        try
        {
            myconnection.Open();
            ConnectedIcons();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = myconnection;

            string update = "UPDATE StaffList SET LastBoot = '" + datenow + "' WHERE StaffID = '" + selectedstaffid + "';";
            var accessUpdateCommand = new  OleDbCommand(update, myconnection);
            accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastBoot", datenow);
            accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("StaffID", selectedstaffid);
            command = accessUpdateCommand;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myconnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

/* I actually just missed the ' marks before my variables in my string update */